# The resulting type when a float variable is divided by an integer variable in c++

Tags: c++

I was solving a question on geeksforgeeks.com on c++ where I determining the resulting type of the variable after operations.

Input:
1
1 2 3 5
gfgc

Output:
4 8 4 8
32 1

```
Example:
Testcase 1:
b/c = 2/3 =>sizeof(2/3)=>float size is 4 bytes

"b/a = 2/1 =>sizeof(2/1)=>double size is 8 bytes"

c/a = 3/1 =>sizeof(3/1)=>integer size is 4 bytes
(c/a)+l =3+5= 8 =>sizeof(8)=>long long size is 8 bytes
sizeof(gfgc) = 32 => It is not 4 because of the reason listed here
sizeof(c) = 1 as it is just a character.
```

Can someone explain the reason behind the output shown in the line in quotes?

Comment: This isn't very clear. Could you please frame it with real code examples? What are the types of all these variables?

Comment: Where is the problem statement? Are we supposed to deduce it from the example testcase? At least provide a link to the page.

Comment: Don't hide the problem statement behind a link to a page.

Comment: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/the-size-of/1/?track=module-1-basics-and-control-structures
Check this out @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: What did I just say 

Answer (score 3):

Given `float a` and `int b` (or vice versa), and the expression `auto c = a/b`, **both `a` and `b` are coerced into `float`s for the division, and `c` is a `float`**.

More generally, if either operand is of a floating-point type, the resulting type will the first in this list that's found in the expression: `long double`, `double`, or `float`; the other operand is converted to that type. If both operands are integers then a similar sort of rule applies.

These are the "usual arithmetic conversions". Refer to [`[expr.arith.conv]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.4).

Comment: I'm trying really hard to understand OP's question. Are you sure you've had? I'm asking because even with your answer I still cannot get the Q...

Comment: @YSC: Think so. I just followed the title: _"The resulting type when a float variable is divided by an integer variable in c++"_. The body is awful though, so I added a bit more broader exploration in case they're asking about `double` instead. Hopefully they'll fix the question for curation reasons but I'm fairly confident the answer will still apply.

Comment: Rep for the good will.